# Is it possible to address individual elements in a stringstream in c++

Tags: c++, string, stringstream

I am looking for a way to address individual elements in a string stream, such as would be done with an array, `arr[n]`. I realize I can simply assign a string with the string stream, `std::string gets  = ss.str()` and address the string, but this seems counter intuitive.

Comment: You could try to use the `rdbuf` inside the strings tream?

Comment: No, there is no way to directly access the individual character of stream buffer, this is not what it is for. But you can access the elements of string representation.

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to sort individual words alphabetically in the string stream using a for loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Stream elements are individual characters and they have positions. However, read and write parts of a stream are separate (`istream` vs `ostream`), so you cannot easily manipulate contents of a stream. And, generally, streams support reading/writing once, only some streams can be rewound.

---

> I'm trying to sort individual words alphabetically in the string stream using a for loop.

You can read all words into a vector and then sort the vector. E.g.:

```
std::vector<std::string> read_words_and_sort(std::istream& s) {
    std::vector<std::string> v(std::istream_iterator<std::string>{s},
                               std::istream_iterator<std::string>{});
    std::sort(v.begin(), v.end());
    return v;
}
```